# Does having a workbook that contains links to others affect the VBA code within it?

Tags: vba

I have a workbook that uses values in the cells to generate tables used in Prophet. If instead of having values in cells, I have links to other workbooks, will this affect the VBA code in anyway? Are there any concerns that I need that I need to be aware of?

Comment: IMHO it will not have any effect on your macros. The only impact it normally has is that the user get asked if he wants to update the links upon opening the workbook...

Answer (score 1):

There will not be an effect to your macro.

Excel stores the value, as well as the link. So even if the link is not refreshed or the 'linked to' workbook is missing, there is still a value to return.

This snippet of code will return the cell value regardless of the link status.

```
A1 = Range("A1").Value
```

The biggest danger is users not refreshing the link, in which case you could be using old values.  It is also possible for your users to break the link which converts the link from a formula to a value.